# Performance impact of QueryPerformanceCounter

Tags: c++, windows, timing

Is there a performance impact from calling QueryPerformanceCounter over a less high-resolution timing method in Windows?

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/387778-queryperformancecounter-performance/ - last post is interesting

Comment: I suggest you do some timing tests comparing `QueryPerformanceCounter` with other "less high-resolution timing methods", and see what differences you observe. :-)

Comment: Like this? http://www.nvidia.com/object/timer_function_performance.html

Comment: @Chris - How do you recommend timing those tests?

Comment: @Bo: Start a timer (of any type). Query one timer type a million times. Stop your timer. Repeat with other timer types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although old, [this Dr Dobb's article](http://drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=184416651&siteSectionName=) gives a nice summary of your options and their costs, pros and cons (see the tables right at the end), including QPC.

TBH, to get real timings for your situation, use a profiler (like AMD's CodeAnalyst) or something like [Dr Fog's performance monitor](http://www.agner.org/optimize/testp.zip)([site](http://www.agner.org/optimize/), which also has some other things of use, depend how far you want to go into the hole of 'how much will this call/instruction/action cost').

Comment: Interesting read - I thought there would be some difference but I didn't expect an ~88x difference between QueryPerformanceCounter and GetTickCount

Comment: @konrad: GetTickCount merely gets the systems current tick and muls it by the current time step, QPC on the other hand queries the on board(on the motherboard, if it exists) high frequency timing device, and iirc it goes into kernel mode to do that, which is expensive. But its to be expected, the trade off is accuracy and grainularity vs speed (one can no longer abuse TSC to get the best of both, due to multicore variable speed cpu's, its a lot trickier to use it correctly). Keep in mind, what someone elses tests show, isn't what you might get, which is why you always test your own setup

Comment: @Necrolis, the variable speed is not a problem if your cpu supports constant tsc (some newer ones do). The problem with multicore is the expense of the serialising operation you have to call *before* rdtsc (e.g. cpuid), as the number of cores increases - the cost of this increases...